# Monit daemon not available after new deployment on OpsWorks

Tags: aws-opsworks, monit, mailman

We are using Monit to monitor mailman service, Worker nodes, and Opsworks agent.
It works fine till new we deploy new release.
On new release monit stops the Mailman Service and Start it.
And when I do SSH into server and check monit status it gives error "error connecting to the monit daemon"

How do I check the cause of monit daemon stops?

Comment: What is the old/new monit version. Had you deleted the old monit status file (see "set statefile" in the monitrc to get the used name).

Comment: We did not upgrade the monit version nor deleted the status file. we simply deploy new release through OpsWorks for changes in project.

Comment: Are you using "monit status" or "monit summary" to get some information?
My problem of understanding is, the error "error connecting to the monit daemon" is not a monit message (I cannot find this message and expect something like "Cannot connect to [localhost]:2812 -- Connection refused").
Are some useful messages available in the monit log file (check the file defined by "set logfile" in the "monitrc")?

Answer (score 0):

Check if an old monit.pid file is still available. Remove the old pid file used by Monit and start Monit again.

See $HOME/.monit.pid or /var/run/monit.pid